# How to make a OnTriggerCollider say a word C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Here is my code

```
public float speed;
public Text countText;
public Text winText;

private Rigidbody rb;
private int count;

void Start ()
{
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    count = 0;
    SetCountText ();
    winText.text = "";
}

void FixedUpdate ()
{
    float moveHorizontal = Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal");
    float moveVertical = Input.GetAxis ("Vertical");

    Vector3 movement = new Vector3 (moveHorizontal, 0.0f, moveVertical);

    rb.AddForce (movement * speed);
}

void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other) 
{
    if (other.gameObject.CompareTag ( "Pick Up"))
    {
        other.gameObject.SetActive (false);
        count = count + 1;
        SetCountText ();
    }
}

void SetCountText ()
{
    countText.text = "Count: " + count.ToString ();
    if (count >= 12)
    {
        winText.text = "You Win!";
    }
}
```

}

At the moment, every time it hits y object, it say Count: Then whatever number of tokens I have collected

Instead of it doing that, I want it to say a word every time I collect my token

Note: I am rookie so please when you answer, explain why you write that in beginner language. If possible, please copy the code, make changes and paste it

Comment: What word you want to show? just set the `countText.text` with that word you want instead of count.

Answer (score 0):

```
countText.text = "a word: " + count.ToString ();
```

the +count.ToString() displays the coincount after "a word". 
If you do not want to show the count you can remove it.

Also note that this will only trigger if the objects tag =="Pick Up".

If you want to use this on a different Object not using a tag you could also change the `other.gameObject.CompareTag ( "Pick Up"))` with

```
other.gameObject.name== "yourobjectname"
```